# Airflow web logging: Flask-AppBuilder logs

Tags: python, flask, airflow, flask-appbuilder

I have an authentication problem within the Airflow Web server. To debug this  I want to set the debug level of `Flask-AppBuilder` to `DEBUG`.
I have changed the following environment variables in `values.yaml`:

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__LOGGING_LEVEL: "DEBUG"
AIRFLOW__LOGGING__FAB_LOGGING_LEVEL: "DEBUG"
AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL: "DEBUG"
```

I can see debug logging for `DAGS` and `Flask`, but not for `Flask-AppBuilder`.

Comment: did you found answer i am also facing this issue

Comment: AIRFLOW__LOGGING__EXTRA_LOGGER_NAMES might be useful

Answer (score 0):

Can you override the Logger?  Perhaps something like:

```
import logging
print("Loggers: " + str(logging.root.manager.loggerDict))
mylogger = logging.getLogger("flask_appbuilder.security.manager")
mylogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```